# Confusión con los paquetes en java

Tags: java

Tengo dos archivos java dentro de dos carpetas individuales y en la carpeta llamada Eje trato de acceder a la clase de la carpeta llamada pro, pero al compilar me muestra que el paquete no existe.  capturas.
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia por favor, desconozco la causa del error.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio. En tu caso concreto deberias sustituir las imagenes de código por texto para facilitarnos poder ayudarte, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas acceder desde la clase contenida en la carpeta `Eje` a la clase de la carpeta `pro`

debes agregar en la clase `Paquete3` el import

```
import Nue.pro.Paquete1;
```